# MySQL converting column of type TEXT to TINYTEXT truncates value at non-intuitive position, why?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I recently ran into a problem where a table had a column of type TEXT inadvertently converted to type TINYTEXT (MySQL version 5.6.24). We were able to restore any truncated data, but the confusing thing was was that we only noticed the problem when certain values for the column started appearing to be truncated at seemingly random positions in the text string.

After trying to wrap my head around what happened I finally realized that each value originally >= 256 chars was truncated to a length equal to the difference between its original length and the nearest lower multiple of 256. Eg:

```
Original Length Truncated Length Difference
257             1                256
350             94               256
597             85               512
```

I then confirmed this is exactly what happens when you convert a TEXT column to TINYTEXT. It's as if it iteratively removes chunks of 256 bytes until the total length is < 256. But why wouldn't it simply just truncate the value to 255 bytes to begin with? Seems like a more efficient operation, but I have no idea about how the internals work.

I couldn't find an explanation on the MySQL documentation. I mean, either way if you have values that exceed the max length you're going to lose data; obviously one wouldn't do this on purpose, but figuring out what happened would have been a bit less confusing if all of the truncated values had length 255.

EDIT: I confirmed this behavior for both the MyISAM and InnoDB storage engines.

EDIT AGAIN: Code to reproduce scenario:

```sql
create temporary table tmp (
    text_col text
)
collate = 'utf8_general_ci'
engine = InnoDB;

create temporary table results (
    current_value text,
    length_text_col int(11),
    char_length_text_col int(11),
    text_col_type char(8)
)
collate = 'utf8_general_ci'
engine = InnoDB;

insert into tmp
    (text_col)
values
    (repeat('a', 257)), -- 1 byte/character
    (repeat('ア', 86)); -- 3 bytes/character

insert into results
select
    text_col as current_value,
    length(text_col) as length_text_col,
    char_length(text_col) as char_length_text_col,
    'TEXT' as text_col_type
from
    tmp;

alter table tmp
change column text_col text_col tinytext;

insert into results
select
    text_col as current_value,
    length(text_col) as length_text_col,
    char_length(text_col) as char_length_text_col,
    'TINYTEXT' as text_col_type
from
    tmp;

select * from results;
```

The above code will select:

```
current_value  length_text_col  char_length_text_col text_col_type
aaaaaaaaaa...  257              257                  TEXT
アアアアア....  258              86                   TEXT
a              1                1                    TINYTEXT
               2                2                    TINYTEXT
```

Comment: Size of `TINYTEXT` is restricted to the 255 bytes, not characters. Some charsets like UTF are multibyte and (sometimes) required more than 255 bytes to store 255 characters.

Comment: @Kondybas Yes, I know, but the column data is truncated to *less than 255 bytes*

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially no good reason to ever use `TINYTEXT`.  And there are some obscure drawback.

If you are using utf8 or utf8mb4, then you may have "multi-byte" characters.  `TINYTEXT` is limited to 255 *bytes*.  `VARCHAR(255)`, which is similar in many ways, is limited to 255 *characters*.

If your text is any any Asian language, then *only* about 85 *characters* can be stored in `TINYTEXT`.  For `VARCHAR(255)`, a full 255 *characters* can be stored.

**More**

I agree that the `ALTER` is messing thing up in a strange way.  Here's a shorter example:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp;
create temporary table tmp (
    text_col text
) collate = 'utf8_general_ci' engine = InnoDB;

insert into tmp
    (text_col)
values
    (repeat('a', 257)), -- 1 byte/character
    (repeat('ア', 86)); -- 3 bytes/character

SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp\G
SELECT text_col, length(text_col) FROM tmp;
alter table tmp
    change column text_col text_col tinytext;
SELECT text_col, length(text_col), HEX(text_col) FROM tmp;  -- Strangly truncated
SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp\G
```

The `HEX` comes back with the *first* two bytes of Katakana 'A', which is `E382A2`, so I will *guess* that the `ALTER` did some kind of modulo -- picking (258 % 256 == 2) bytes to keep.

Fails for me on 5.5.43, 5.6.22 and 8.0.2.  On the other hand, MariaDB 10.0.28 and 10.3.7 complain about the `ALTER`:

```
mysql> alter table tmp
    ->     change column text_col text_col tinytext;
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'text_col' at row 1
```

File a bug at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Like I said in the original post, no one would ever do what happened in the incident I described on purpose, and I am aware of the reasons why it's probably better to use a different datatype in most situations, but my question was not regarding this.

Comment: @dcsmith926 - I hope I answered the Question that was asked, too.

Comment: Sorry, my question was more just for my curiosity about why the truncation occurs in the particular manner that it does. Instead of being truncated to 255 bytes (what I, and I think most others would _expect_), the data is truncated to [# original bytes] - [nearest lower multiple of 256]

Comment: @dcsmith926 - `VARCHAR` counts characters; `TEXT` counts bytes.  Utf8/utf8mb4 confuses the issue by not having a 1:1 mapping between characters and bytes.

Comment: Yes, I already know that. My question is about why the `TINYTEXT` gets truncated to _less than 255 **bytes**_. I don't know how to be more clear, but I think I'll only find my answer in the source code itself. It's not super important anyway

Comment: @dcsmith926 - I would expect `TINYTEXT` to be truncated at a _character_ boundary.  For example if there is room for 1 more byte, but the next character is a 3-byter, then you might get only 254 bytes put in the column.  Use `LENGTH()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()` to investigate.

Comment: See the code I added to my original question above.

Comment: @dcsmith926 - File a bug with mysql , but not mariadb.  See my additions.